# E-mail campaign using a single image with a text fallback?

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments

I am working on an email campaign which will be using a single image. For email clients that don't support images, or for users who have disabled images manually, what would be the best way to include a text-based fallback?

Currently I am thinking I should just create a `.txt` file and send it as an attachment along with the inline image, but wondering if there is an industry standard different from this.

Answer (score 1):

Do not attach a .txt file no one will open it and the conversion rate of non image clients will be zero.

**Place the text in the alt.** Most email clients will display the text if it can not or will not display the image.

```
<img src=”youimage.jpg” width=”X″ height=”X″ alt=”Here is your text.”>
```

You can also use inline styling in img tags. Like so

```
<img src=”youimage.jpg” width=”X″ height=”X″ alt=”Here is your text.” style=”font-family: Arial; color: #880000; font-style: bold; font-size: 2em;”>
```

Having said that you should try to build emails that are not just a single image. I understand the appeal of just mocking something up in photoshop and sending it but it's bad practice.